# Why return null in while loop R

Tags: r

I wanted to store the result in a vector if it satisfy the if statement, but the return value is always null. How can I make it to return the value of the loop?

```
url <- "http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/legierung.dat" 
data <- read.table(url, header = TRUE)
breaking = data[,4]
c = mean(breaking)
b  = 1
p = data
oo <- c()
var = function(){
  if(a > c){
    oo<-c(oo,"High")
  }else{
    oo = c(oo,"Low")
  }
  return(oo)
} 

count = 0
while(count <=length(p[,4])){
  a = p[(b),4]
  b = b+1
  var()
  count = count+1 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this in a very complicated way.

As far as I could read your code I think you want `'High'` for values which are greater than mean of `Breaking` column and `'Low'` otherwise. You can do this with `ifelse` statement.

```
mean_breaking <- mean(p$breaking)
p$new_col <- ifelse(p$breaking > mean_breaking, 'High', 'Low')
```

The same can be done without `ifelse` as well :

```
p$new_col <- c('Low', 'High')[(p$breaking > c) + 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get values added to oo you either need to assign var() to oo within your loop

Example:

```
while(count <=length(p[,4])){
    a = p[(b),4]
    b = b+1
    oo <- var()
    count = count+1 
}
```

Or do this assignment within your function instead of returning the value

Example:

```
var = function(){
  if(a > c){
    oo<-c(oo,"High")
  }else{
    oo = c(oo,"Low")
  }
  oo <<- oo
}
```

This works because `<<-` assigns oo as oo in the parent environment.

Comment: Ur method works. is it because i did not assign a variable to receive the return value that makes me cannot get the return value?

Comment: Yes! you had assigned null to oo and then when your function was called it would evaluate it and return the value but it didn't save it anywhere.